# How to send special characters to Spring controller through text box

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

"" double quote issue

In jsp a property name - ${name} contains **abc "test"** value

```
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="200" id="name" value="${name}">
```

But while displaying value in the text filed it is displaying only **abc** remaining content it is not displaying

I fixed with the help of following one

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="200" id="name" value="${fn:escapeXml(name)}" >
```

By using that  function, special characters(ƒΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜ) not supporting

Comment: you are using servlet ?

Comment: no @VinayHegde, we are using spring mvc. If you want that code i will send it